# javascript for...in statement. Exclude first and last iteration. And split loop multiple of 12

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript calculator coded not by me and I'm doing front-end coding, to make it usable on web page with UI. There's a piece of code when all calculations are done and it starts to prepare data for UI.

```
            for (var RowIndex in Calc.Graphic)
            {
                Row = Calc.Graphic[RowIndex];
            Graph += "<tr>";
            Graph += "<td>"+ RowIndex +"</td>";
            Graph += "<td>" + Row.SummPay + "</td>";
            Graph += "</tr>";

            }
```

This loop males table with payment schedule, and I need to exlude from it first and last iteration because it technical data. RowIndex - is month count and Row.SummPay is Summ.
Here's the table after javascript work. How can I exclude 0 and 13.

```
Month SummPay
0   0
1   84501
2   70418
3   58682
4   48901
5   40751
6   33960
7   28300
8   23583
9   19653
10  16378
11  13648
12  11225
13  1000
```

And if there's more then 12 month stop loop and start forming new table floated left like

```
1   84501   13 11225
2   70418   14 11225
3   58682   15 11225
4   48901   16 11225
5   40751   17 11225
6   33960   18 11225
7   28300   19 11225
8   23583   20 11225
9   19653   21 11225
10  16378   22 11225
11  13648   23 11225
12  11225   24 11225
```

Comment: Please, please *do not* use `for..in` for iterating over arrays in javascript.. Please! Just use a for loop inclusive for the indexes you want.

Comment: Well there's nothing I can do with back-end code, sorry

Comment: @halofourteen: The code you posted is backend code?

Comment: @halofourteen You can't edit the javascript? What is it that you want to do exactly? Remove the TR elements from the DOM after they have been rendered?

Comment: @Quintin Robinson this part I can edit, but I can't change whole JS part of calculator

Comment: By iterating array this way you can get undefined behavior, cause some frameworks adds new functionalities to standart prototypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Don't use for ... in.
Instead, use this for the first thing.

From what I understand, it should be a product of 12. In which case:

```
        for (var RowNumber = 1; RowNumber < 13; RowNumber ++)
        {
            Graph += "<tr>";
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < Calc.Graphic.length / 12; colIndex ++){
                var rowIndex = RowNumber + 12*colIndex
                Row = Calc.Graphic[rowIndex];
                Graph += "<td>"+ rowIndex +"</td>";
                Graph += "<td>" + Row.SummPay + "</td>";
            }
            Graph += "</tr>";
        }
```